# Android Studio + MapQuest: UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load mapbox-gl from loader

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mapbox-gl, mapquest

I'm trying to create a basic map aplication with mapquest in android studio. Not having to much luck so far.

This is the [official documentation](https://developer.mapquest.com/documentation/android-sdk/).

The error is:

> Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load mapbox-gl from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/hermes.com.uy.zfbffs-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/hermes.com.uy.zfbffs-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]]: findLibrary returned null

The full error log is pasted below.

I read in stackoverflow some similar questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25324057/unsatisfiedlinkerror-couldnt-load-x-from-loader) and [this otherone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33660282/unsatisfiedlinkerror-couldnt-load-crashlytics-from-loader-dalvik-system-pathcl), but don't seem to help.

Has anyone encountered this issue?

Any help is welcome.

Best,
    Federico.

Full LogCat:

> 01-18 13:51:56.940 16152-16152/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION:
>   main
>                                                      java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{hermes.com.uy.zfbffs/hermes.com.uy.zfbffs.MainActivity}:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Error
>   inflating class com.mapquest.mapping.maps.MapView
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
>                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
>                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
>                                                          at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>                                                       Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Error
>   inflating class com.mapquest.mapping.maps.MapView
>                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
>                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
>                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
>                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
>                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
>                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
>                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284)
>                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
>                                                          at hermes.com.uy.zfbffs.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:17)
>                                                          at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
>                                                          at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261) 
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141) 
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256) 
>                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
>                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103) 
>                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737) 
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
>                                                          at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
>                                                       Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
>                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
>                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
>                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696) 
>                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
>                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
>                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
>                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
>                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284) 
>                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
>                                                          at hermes.com.uy.zfbffs.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:17) 
>                                                          at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133) 
>                                                          at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175) 
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261) 
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141) 
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256) 
>                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
>                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103) 
>                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737) 
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
>                                                          at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
>                                                       Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load mapbox-gl from loader
>   dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/hermes.com.uy.zfbffs-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/hermes.com.uy.zfbffs-1,
>   /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]]: findLibrary returned null
>                                                          at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:355)
>                                                          at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:525)
>                                                          at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.NativeMapView.(NativeMapView.java:46)
>                                                          at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView.initialize(MapView.java:197)
>                                                          at com.mapquest.mapping.maps.MapView.initialize(MapView.java:104)
>                                                          at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView.(MapView.java:167)
>                                                          at com.mapquest.mapping.maps.MapView.(MapView.java:84)
>                                                          at com.mapquest.mapping.maps.MapView.(MapView.java:79)
>                                                          at com.mapquest.mapping.maps.MapView.(MapView.java:75)
>                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
>                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417) 
>                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594) 
>                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696) 
>                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
>                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
>                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
>                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
>                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284) 
>                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
>                                                          at hermes.com.uy.zfbffs.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:17) 
>                                                          at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133) 
>                                                          at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175) 
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261) 
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141) 
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256) 
>                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
>                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103) 
>                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737) 
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
>                                                          at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)  01-18 13:56:57.130
>   16152-16152/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 16152 SIG: 9

Comment: The development team is working on updating the documentation to address this issue. I hope to see this update go live next week. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Thanks Brian. I'll be checking next week for updates.

Comment: The documentation update will take a little longer than I estimated so I added the updated information to your forum post. This should help get up and running. https://developer.mapquest.com/forum/help-hello-world-mapquest-app-android-studio

Comment: Thanks Brian, now it is working. But with some flaws I think. 1) Does ti require a MinSDKVersion? I was working with API15 and did not run, it does with API24 (only tried those two). 2) There is a constant message in LogCat saying "E/emuglGLESv2_enc: a vertex attribute index out of boundary is detected. Skipping corresponding vertex attribute.", it this normal? Will try the rest of the examples of the documentation and let you know. Thanks again. Federico.

Comment: Brian, all examples work great except for "Use the User's Location". There is one correction to be made and one problem I could not solve:

Correction) "ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.XXX)" should be changed to "this.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.XXX)". This is done two times in the method "enableUserTracking".

Problem) "mapView.setMyLocationTrackingMode(MyLocationTracking.TRACKING_FOLLOW)" says that "setMyLocation is not public. Cannot be accessed from outside the package."